# Using C-style struct/typedef from within C++

Tags: c++, c, struct, typedef, extern

I have a project that is mixing C and C++.  In a C header file, I have code like this:

```
typedef struct mystruct* mystruct;
struct mystruct {
    // whatever struct needs
};
```

And to use this in the C++ file, I am doing:

```
extern "C" {
#include "mystruct.h"
}
```

So you see that I am creating an opaque pointer using the same names.  This is fine in C but not in C++ (because of the requirement to instantiate using the struct keyword in C but not in C++).  However, I get an error (conflicting declarations) when trying to compile the C++ code.  I thought that using the `extern "C"` would make the compiler treat the C header as C, but it seems to still be using it as C++.  Is there any explanation for what is happening here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I thought that using the `extern "C"` would make the compiler treat the C header as C

No. The only thing that `extern "C"` does is control name mangling. The code is still compiled as C++ (though things that require mangled names, such as namespaces or templates, won’t work). In particular, the rule concerning `struct` identifiers still applies.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the term `control name mangling` ? I amn't sure what it means. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahesh “control” is a verb. `extern "C"` *controls* [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Answer (score 1):

extern "C" enforces C linkage, as opposed to mangled C++ linkage. extern "C" does not enforce full C compliance such as dynamically sizable arrays, etc.